# How do I skip the OpenID approval screen when developing a Java-based Google App Engine app for the Chrome Web Store?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-chrome, openid, google-openid

I've developed a Chrome Web Store app using Google App Engine. I'd like to follow these instructions: http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/identify_user.html#realm

But I need to call `User::getFederatedIdentity()` so that I can call the Chrome Web Store licensing server and find out if the user has purchased my app.

The trouble with that is, in order for `UserService::getCurrentUser()` to work, the user needs to be logged in.

The trouble with *that* is, when I call `UserService::createLoginURL()` to generate a redirect URL, the redirect URL takes the user to... the OpenID approval screen. This happens even though I've set the App's OpenID realm, as per the instructions in the page linked above.

Is there a way for me to do what I want but still use the `User` and `UserService` classes?

(Possibly a legit alternate phrasing for this entire question: using Google App Engine's `UserService` class, is there a way to request permission from the user to access their federated identiy, *without* also requesting permission to access their email address?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please reread [how to skip the OpenID approval screen](http://code.google.com/chrome/webstore/docs/identify_user.html#realm). Have you set the realm? And are you asking for any information other than the URL? If you request the user's email address (or other information), then it is necessary to inform the user and obtain their permission to grant access to that information.

Comment: I have set the realm, using the realm param passed into the URL for the the OpenID approval screen. As for asking for the user's email address -- that's part of what I'm trying to figure out how _not_ to do, using GAE's UserService class.